# What kind of frame is this the number is. ACS8E03286

Tags: frames

[image]. This a green frame and I'm trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: I think it's a bicycle.  Seriously, you need to take more photos from different angles. We can't tell much from what you've given us.

Comment: @RoboKaren no its a white and gold frame !

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to tell by the numbers

Comment: @Criggie No, it's black and blue!

Comment: @JamesFolk sadly the numbers mean little.  Each manufacturer may have their own scheme, but identifying the format means you need to know the maker of the frame.  As it stands, you have a bare frame of a colour and a a quality, and you can choose to assemble it into a bike.  The brand doesn't mean a lot at this point.

Comment: TBH it looks like a baby MTB rather than a BMX, from your photo.  There appears to be a canti brake boss on the left seat stay, and the downtube has that beefy ovalised look of the early 90s.    If you can add photos of the dropouts, the head tube badge, and anything that looks unique we might be able to help more.

Comment: Your best source of information is whoever/whereever you got it from in the first place.

Comment: @Criggie A lot of mid-2000s frames had large ovalised downtubes and a lot of the newer, low end completes I've seen, still do. That brake-mount looks like a welded version of the 990 mounts that are quite common on the more high-end stuff these days and looks very similar to some of the ones I've seen on cheaper frames in the past few years. It's placement on the top of the seat-stay is quite interesting. I can't say I've seen them there on a good BMX frame of any age.

Comment: @PhilipGibbons yes there are heaps of possibilities.  OP can narrow down the options by providing more information, but that might not be coming.

Answer (score 2):

I've never found any rhyme or reason to the numbers on BMX frames. In my experience, you need to know the brand as well as the serial and then contact said brand.

It looks pretty low end from the above photo with the upwards brake mounts on the seatstay and what looks to be an American BB? If I had to guess, it came from a low end complete some time in the past 5-10 years. It is very hard to tell anything from the picture above and age is quite hard to guess with BMX frames.